# Debugging an app with NSight Visual Studio edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directx-11, nsight

I am using VS 2012 with NV NSight on my host/Dev machine. I am trying to debug graphics applications on my test machine with 2 NV GPU's. I am not able to connect to intended app (No DirectX code for the app is involved) on remote test machine (remote settings checked multiple times) to get the D3D API call log, frame debugging capabilities enabled.

All I can see is that first three options of NSight menu in VS 2012 are greyed out.

Further, I searched around and I found that I can use AMD's GPU Perf Studio 2 to launch an app on test machine and connect to this session (GPU Perf Studio 2 + App) from my dev machine to get D3D API call log, frame debugging etc.

My question is, can NSight VS 2012 edition mimic this capability of GPU Perf Studio 2 ? If so, then how?

P.S: It is imperative that I use VS 2012 NV NSight tool to debug this app.And I do not have the code for this app.I just want to attach to its process on remote test machine with NV GPU's and debug its frames,get DirectX API calls etc.

Comment: Hi, which specific menus are greyed out? and which version of Nsight are you using?

Comment: Menu Items Start GPU/CUDA/Graphics Debugging are greyed out. I am using Nsight version 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you posted on NVIDIA's forum as well.  Let's move to:  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/642941/nsight-visual-studio-edition/debugging-an-app-with-nsight-visual-studio-edition/